# How do you get the permissions to add the description to a new tag?

Tags: support

When you add a new tag, how do you get the permissions to add a description for it. I just added that tag [elixir-iex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir-iex) but it looks lonely on its own without a description?

Comment: You can suggest an excerpt and wiki for the tag. Make sure it isn't plagiarized. Both excerpt and wiki should explain how and when to use the tag, so no marketing/sales pitch for the product/tool/lib. Once it is in the queue it needs some reviewers to approve your texts

Comment: Where do you suggest an excerpt and wiki for the tag, through  a normal question?

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/elixir-iex/info press the big blue button below the text  named Create Tag Info

Answer (score 2):

From the [tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/elixir-iex/info) *All registered users may propose new tag wikis.*

[image]

Just click the button ....